# Beamer: Display all images only once in article mode

Tags: beamerarticle, count

I'm creating a beamer presentation in which I include several images, of which some of them are included in multiple frames. I'm also creating an `article` version of this presentation with

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
```

In the article version, I would like all images to be included only once. More specifically, I would like to include only the instantiation of each image.

I know it is possible to achieve this by using `\mode<beamer>{...}` on all instances of an image that comes after the first instance of that image, but that strategy is error prone since I might accidentally forget to use the `\mode<beamer>{...}` wrapper at some place were it should be used, or I might move frames around so that the instance that doesn't have the wrapper around it ends up not being the first instance of that image.

So, is it possible to automatically wrap all instances of the same image that is not the first instance of that image in `\mode<beamer>{...}`?

Comment: In short: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: What are the use cases you need? Only `\includegraphics` or other stuff, too? In figure environment or not (would be harder)? Please provide a MWE which shows your use cases.

Answer (score 2):

Prove of concept like MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\LetLtxMacro\includegraphicsBAK\includegraphics

\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{%
  \ifcsname image_#2\endcsname% macro already exists
    \mode<beamer>{\includegraphicsBAK[#1]{#2}}%
  \else%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname image_#2\endcsname{}%
    \includegraphicsBAK[#1]{#2}%
  \fi}



\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{foo}{bar}%>>>
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{frame}%<<<

\end{document}
```